# How do I locate and perform a command on all executable files matching a given pattern?

Tags: security, find, file-permissions

How I identify all files on my Unix (OS X) system matching a particular pattern that have their executable bit set, so that I can perform a command on them?

For example, I'd like to locate all `.doc` files created before a given date that [have any executable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29922727/656912) bit set, and `chmod a-x` them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
find . -name '*.doc' -perm +0111 -exec chmod a-x ''{}'' ";"
```

It will depend on exactly what you mean by "executable".